# Failed to push to Heroku (failed to compile app)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5, bundler

I've been using Heroku to host my Rails 5 app for a while, and it has worked great until today. Just tried pushing the latest update and got this error:

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Ruby app detected
/tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/39f112f50b07a72959c8a346ce561f7cb404a86c/bin/compile: line 3: heroku/ruby: No such file or directory
This buildpack is no longer supported, please use  which now supports Bundler 2 directly
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
 !     Push failed
```

My guess is that I am not using the latest version of bundler for my app? If this is the case, how would I fix this? Or maybe it is something different?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Potential solution:
https://github.com/rubygems/bundler/issues/6784

Try: `heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/bundler/heroku-buildpack-bundler2`

Comment: I tried this, and receivd this: Error: The buildpack https://github.com/bundler/heroku-buildpack-bundler2 is already set on your app.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove buildpack `https://github.com/bundler/heroku-buildpack-bundler2` from your project on heroku setting